# Is this link L10a169?

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, quantum-computation

Please consider the following link

[image]

[image]

I am using SnapPy with the following code

```
  In[1]: LS = Link([[6, 10, 1, 7],[8, 18, 7, 19],[11, 6, 12, 5],[17, 12, 18, 13],[4, 16, 5, 17],[15, 11, 16, 14],[14, 4, 13, 3],[20, 2, 19, 1],[2, 9, 3, 8],[9, 20, 10, 15]])

In[2]: LSI1=LS.exterior()

In[3]: LSI1.volume()
Out[3]: 17.4771408175

In[4]: LSI1.identify()
```

and the output from SnapPy is

```
Out[4]: [10^4_17(0,0)(0,0)(0,0)(0,0), L10a169(0,0)(0,0)(0,0)(0,0)]
```

Then I am concluding that the considered link is L10a169:

[image]

which corresponds to the  "Japanese family symbol":

[image]

The Jones polynomial computed from the PD code is given by

[image]

and the Jones polynomial for L10a169 is given by (http://katlas.org/wiki/L10a169)

[image]

As we can see the two Jones polynomials only differ by a multiplicative monomial.

The corresponding Khovanov-Poincaré polynomial is given by
[image]

The link L10a169 has unlinking number 3, as it can be converted to the trivial link with 4 components by changing the 3 crossings indicated in the following  figure (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01386.pdf )

[image]

Please could you confirm such identification?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the knot on the left supposed to mean ($10^4_{17}$)?

Comment: Have you yourself compared it to the picture in http://katlas.org/wiki/L10a169?  (Or made it out of string to see if you can isotope it?)